# Can ActiveAdmin connect to an API?

Tags: activeadmin

I know ActiveAdmin looks at your models to pull in information into its dashboard.  I'm wondering if ActiveAdmin can be configured to pull in API Endpoints?  For instance I'd like to have one instance of ActiveAdmin running and I'd like to feed it multiple Project endpoints that have different schemas.

This is to prevent having to have an ActiveAdmin instance running for every Rails app we build.

Thoughts?  Do I need to provide more information?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveAdmin relies heavily on information ActiveRecord and the database provide, which is how it's able to dynamically build your tables and forms. It isn't designed to plug into APIs like you're talking about. Best bet is to just include the gem and build the panels for the stuff you need within your Rails app.